# how to view data an image in azure container register

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

I am new in azure portal. I push a docker image to azure container resgistry and then I create an web app where I use that image. Now want to see all my data in the image or I need that data because every time my app execute it create some new file so I need these files or I want to view these  files.
can someone please tell me how can I do that?`
This is my docker file.

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  ca-certificates \
  curl

ARG NODE_VERSION=14.16.0
ARG NODE_PACKAGE=node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64
ARG NODE_HOME=/opt/$NODE_PACKAGE

ENV NODE_PATH $NODE_HOME/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NODE_HOME/bin:$PATH

RUN curl https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/$NODE_PACKAGE.tar.gz | tar -xzC /opt/


COPY environment.yml .
COPY requirements.txt .


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN conda install -c conda-forge librosa
WORKDIR /with


RUN mkdir /app1

COPY model /app1/model
COPY assets /app1/assets
COPY build /app1/build
COPY node_modules /app1/node_modules
RUN apt-get install -y openssh \
     && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd 

# Copy the sshd_config file to the /etc/ssh/ directory
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/

EXPOSE 8080 2222
# CMD ["python", "/app1/model/main.py", "/app1/assets/uploads/file.txt"]
CMD ["node", "/app1/build/server.js"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you push your image into the ACR and then deploy it to the Web App. If you want to see the data inside the image, here you'd better call it container, you need to ssh into the running container in Web App. To do this, you need to make sure that the ssh was enabled in the image. If not, follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh) to enable it. If the ssh already enabled, then you can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session) to ssh into the container to see the data as you want.

Comment: but I already expose 8080 ...{
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "/app1/build/server.js"] 
}. so what I need to do?

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan You can expose both 8080 and 2222 as the example shown.

Comment: it gave me. { /bin/sh: 1: apk: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add openssh      && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd' returned a non-zero code: 127} when i build {RUN apk add openssh \
     && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd }..

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan It's just an example to show you how to install the ssh. You need to change the command to match your base image.

Comment: can I use {apt-get install} instead of {apk add}?

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan I don't know which base image you use. For example, if you use `apt-get` to install other packages in the Dockerfile, then yes, you need to use this command to install the ssh.

Comment: I share my docker file above.. Can u please tell how I install SSH?

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan That's right. The only thing you need to do is to run the ssh server. You can take a look at the example [here](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/node/blob/master/10.14/Dockerfile). This Dockerfile shows you all the steps that how to enable the ssh.

Comment: thanks buddy.. U r savier.. I will try it.

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan Any updates? Do you solve it?

Comment: no. i build { RUN apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends openssh-server vim curl wget tcptraceroute openrc \ && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/} i also push on azure, but i show same error {"SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.16.0.4:2222Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.16.0.4:2222 CREDENTIALS"} can u please which part of the code i have to use? its not working for now.

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan You also need to start the ssh server. Take a look at the `ssh_setup.sh` file.

Comment: where is that file?

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan I show you the Dockerfile in the comment, you can go to the previous level, the file is there.

Comment: okk.can u pleae tell me which part of the code i have to use?

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan Not sure. But you can try the first and the last if block.

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan And you can follow the steps [here](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/node/blob/master/10.14/startup/init_container.sh#L25) to run the ssh server.

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan Waiting for the result.

Comment: @SubhashKalicharan Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?